# Python list index out of range error that is baffling me

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to put together a flask app that works for a database as a final project for a class.  I'm at the very end, and am encountering an error that baffles me.  I'm pretty new to Python so my hope is that there is something very basic I'm missing here...

Since it's flask, there are a bunch of `html` files that go with it, so it's hard to reproduce an MWE here.  Here's the basic issue though:

In this function

```
@app.route('/view_meal', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_meal():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_meal_id = request.form['selected_meal']
    #get all the food_items associated with this meal
    rows = display_table('meal', where_condition=f"id = '{selected_meal_id}'")
    food1 = display_table('food_item', where_condition=f"id = '{rows[4]}'")
    food2 = display_table('food_item', where_condition=f"id = '{rows[5]}'")
    food3 = display_table('food_item', where_condition=f"id = '{rows[6]}'")
    food4 = display_table('food_item', where_condition=f"id = '{rows[7]}'")
    food5 = display_table('food_item', where_condition=f"id = '{rows[8]}'")
    foods = [food1, food2, food3, food4, food5]
    return render_template('display_meal.html', rows = rows, foods=foods)
  else:
    rows = display_table('meal')
    return render_template('view_meal.html', items=rows)
```

In my first iteration, I was just grabbing the id_numbers associated with the different foods and that worked fine.  So I know that I'm correctly getting the `selected_meal_id` from the form, and that the line

```
rows = display_table('meal', where_condition=f"id = '{selected_meal_id}'")
```

is correctly querying the database.  The `display_table` function is just a `SELECT * FROM` with the table name and `WHERE` clause passed in.

As a further test, in a separate small Python file I queried that database for the meal_id I'm using

```
result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM meal WHERE id='PCKCMH0S'").fetchall()
print(result)
```

and this is the result

> [('PCKCMH0S', 'English Breakfast', 'Fatty', '3/9/2024', 'BQD3MPHM',
> '77WWB0BQ', 'QGH6DV8S', 'I4VD1IE7', 'QGH6DV8S')]

So that is what should be in `rows`

But the line

```
food1 = display_table('food_item', where_condition=f"id = '{rows[4]}'")
```

is throwing a `list index out of range` with the `rows[4]` underlined.  What am I missing here?  There should be nine elements in `rows`

Comment: That's a list containing a single tuple. It's out of range because the outer list only has a single element. You want `rows[0][4]` to get the tuple, then access the 5th element in that tuple.

Comment: sigh...I figured it was something dumb like that....if you want to make this an answer I'll happily accept it @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rows = [('PCKCMH0S', 'English Breakfast', 'Fatty', '3/9/2024', 'BQD3MPHM', '77WWB0BQ', 'QGH6DV8S', 'I4VD1IE7', 'QGH6DV8S')]
```

This is a list containing a single tuple. `rows[4]` is then trying to get the fifth element from that outer list, but since it only contains a single element, this will error-out.

The fix is to get the tuple, *then* index that tuple. Something like:

```
rows = display_table('meal', where_condition=f"id = '{selected_meal_id}'")
row = rows[0]

food1 = display_table('food_item', where_condition=f"id = '{row[4]}'")
food2 = display_table('food_item', where_condition=f"id = '{row[5]}'")
```

Comment: `food1 = display_table('food_item', where_condition=f"id = '{rows[0][4]}'")` did it